# SharedPreferences getString always returns default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here is my code:

```
public void saveValue(String value, String forKey) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
    editor.putString(value, forKey);
    editor.commit();
    SharedPreferences p = getSharedPreferences();
    System.out.println("JUST SET TO SharedPreferences" + p.getString(forKey, ""));
}
```

in Logcat:

```
JUST SET TO SharedPreferences
```

But when app stops on the breakpoint I see that values are actually stored in

[image: debugger output]

I'm running app on the emulator.

How do I read that values? Thanks!

Comment: You made a mistake in the line editor.putString(value, forKey); switch these two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `forKey` as the key which was originally added as a value in the `SharedPreferences` and not as key here:

`editor.putString(value, forKey);`

as you can see above the `value` is the **key** and the `forKey` is the **value**

so therefore when you are getting the value from the `SharedPreferences` you should use the key to get the value:

`p.getString(value, "") //dont use forKey as the value`

***or*** you should switch one another

`editor.putString(forKey, value);`

so the `forkey` will work

Answer (score 1):

I think you switched the key and value here `editor.putString(value, forKey);`.

The signature is `putString (String key, String value)`.